# Scala's Empty Set: ... doesn't conform to expected type Set[Nothing]

Tags: scala, set

I am new to Scala's Set. I was trying to concatenate a Set with an empty Set. The code follows:

```
def getAllSlots(preferences: Map[Band, List[Slot]]): Set[Slot] = {
  preferences.foldLeft(Set.empty){(r,c) => c match {
    case (_, li) => li.toSet ++ r
    case _ => r
  }}
}
```

The error happened when I am trying to do `li.toSet ++ r`, complaining that `... doesn't conform to expected type Set[Nothing]`. Then, I have no idea how to build up a Set starting from an empty one.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What exactly is `...`?

Comment: @Bergi `...` is the type detailed of type `Slot`. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to help the compiler to infer the right type, it doesn't have enough informations to figure out that you mean `Set[Slot]`, `empty` takes a type parameter:

```
def getAllSlots(preferences: Map[Band, List[Slot]]): Set[Slot] = {
  preferences.foldLeft(Set.empty[Slot]){(r,c) => c match {
    case (_, li) => li.toSet ++ r
    case _ => r
  }}
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! I have just tried out and it works like charm! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Simpler and neat Solution**

```
preferences.valuesIterator.flatten.toSet
```

Get all the values of the preferences map using `valuesIterator` and then `flatten` and then convert to set using `toSet` function.

`getAllSlots` function becomes

```
def getAllSlots(preferences: Map[Band, List[Slot]]): Set[Slot] = 
  preferences.valuesIterator.flatten.toSet
```

Comment: `valuesIterator` would be better, so you don't construct unnecessary intermediate collection.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks for the suggestion changed it to valuesIterator

Comment: Wow it's nice. Thanks for an even more efficient way!